# Different styling of the same <a> hyperlink in one line

Tags: html, hyperlink, tags, href

I'm bulding a website where you can see a bit complicated situation: http://test.internet.az.pl/panel/lost_password.php

I want the same dotted line under my text as in this link showing under "Powrót do strony logowania >"

So I needed to create 3 different  in order to remove it, one for text, one for space and one for ">" image symbol:

```
<div class="lost_password" style="float:right; margin-top:-27px; margin-left:25px">
      <a class="a" href="index.php">Powrót do strony logowania</a>
      <a style="border:0px; text-decoration:none" href="index.php"></a>
      <a href="index.php"><img alt="Powrót do strony logowania" src="gfx/arrow.png" style="border:0px"></a>
</div>
```

Is there any way to reduce this code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use spans and img within one anchor.

Something like this:

```
<a class="a" href="index.php">
    <span>Powrót do strony logowania</span> <img alt="Powrót do strony logowania" src="gfx/arrow.png" />
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a.a span {border-bottom: 1px dotted;}
a.a img {border: 0;}
```

Btw. try to avoid inline styling.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use three `<a>` tags, use a `<span>` inside the anchor:

```
<div class="lost_password" style="float:right; margin-top:-27px; margin-left:25px">
  <a href="index.php">
    <span class="dotted">Powrót do strony logowania</span> <img alt="Powrót do strony logowania" src="gfx/arrow.png" style="border:0px">
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a { /* general anchor rules */ }
.dotted { border-bottom: 1px dotted; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `span` tag

Try this code:

```
<div class="lost_password" style="float:right; margin-top:-27px; margin-left:25px">
  <a href="index.php">
    <span class="dot">Powrót do strony logowania</span> <img alt="Powrót do strony logowania" src="gfx/arrow.png" style="border:0px">
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a{
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
}
.dot{ border-bottom: 1px dotted; }
.dot:hover{ border-bottom: none; }
```